# I am facing an error after changing the min sdk version from flutter,minsdk version to a numerical value ie. 16

Tags: android, flutter, dart

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.

> Multiple task action failures occurred:
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
> > The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
> dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
> is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-16).
> Dependency: androidx.window:window-java:1.0.0-beta04.
> AAR metadata file: C:\Users\smjro.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\ad201fac15a88598107ec645f351f5b4\jetified-window-java-1.0.0-beta04\META-INF\com\android\build\gradle\aar-metadata.properties.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
> > The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
> dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
> is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-16).
> Dependency: androidx.window:window:1.0.0-beta04.
> AAR metadata file: C:\Users\smjro.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\03c633e46d75bfb21f082f0417f55161\jetified-window-1.0.0-beta04\META-INF\com\android\build\gradle\aar-metadata.properties.

Answer (score 0):

Set both compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion to 31 in your build.gradle(app) file.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 31 // <-- This
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.app"
        targetSdkVersion 31 // <-- and this too
        // ...
    }
}
```